# Return single entity from wcf data service

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services

I just wanted to know how to return a single entity from a wcf data service?

I want to provide a methode `public User Login(string username, string password)` and return the loggedin user to the user interface.

Thanks!

andi

Comment: Seems like an common task with WCF. Have you tried to make a prototype? Do you actually have any code to share with us? Otherwise your post really has no content.

Comment: No it's not a common task. In fact, it's not possible in a data service.

Answer (score 2):

Old question is old, but you'll want to define a [Service Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744841.aspx):

```
[WebGet]
[SingleResult]
public User GetAuthenticatedUser(string username, string password) {
    //
    // Fetch and return the user
    // with the given parameters
    //
}
```

However the `username` and `password` are passed in clear text via the URI. A better option would be pulling the `username` and `password` data from the `Authorization` header of the HTTP request, encrypting the request over the wire (*SSL*). A simple example could be defining a constructor for the Data Service, and in it attaching to the `ProcessingRequest` event:

```
public MyDataService() {
    this.ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += (o, e) => { 
        // 
        // Do stuff with e.OperationContext.RequestHeaders["Authorization"]
        // storing the result into an instance property
        //
    };
}
```

With a `User GetCurrentUser()` service operation that references the authorization property for the `username` and `password`, instead of accepting them as `GET` querystring parameters.

Comment: You forgot to mention what is the file where `SingleResult` declaration is written.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you.

I assume User is your entity table.

```
public User Login(string username,string password)
{
   Entity obj = new Entity();
   User objUser = (from U in obj.User where U.username = username and U.password = password Select U).Single();
   return objUser;
}
```

This works fine for me I hope it helps you.